# Select2-drop incorrect top position

Tags: jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

When i focused on select2 field at first, dropdown opens all right

[image: Anything is all right]

But when I select one of the items there is wrong top position of dropdown

[image: Wrong position]

And if I unfocus and focus again there is no problem with dropdown

[image: Correct again]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

For those arriving from google as I did:

The wrong position of the dropdown occurs the first time you click the dropdown and the first time you click the dropdown after a search that has no results.

[Here is a workaround](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41#issuecomment-310825598) that seems to work for many people (including me). My implementation below:

```html
<select class="form-control" data-use-select2="true" name="assessment[assigned_to_id]" id="assessment_assigned_to_id">
<option value="">Select User...</option>
<option value="12">org0user0@test.com</option>
<option value="11">org0user1@test.com</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" data-use-select2="true" name="assessment[approver_id]" id="assessment_approver_id" >
<option value="">Select User...</option>
<option value="12">org0user0@test.com</option>
<option value="11">org0user1@test.com</option>
</select>
```

```
    // data-select2 conflicts with library code. data-something-select2 works
    // set the dropdownParent to fix positioning error
    // https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41#issuecomment-310825598
    $("select[data-use-select2]").each(function() {
        $(this).select2({
            theme: "bootstrap4",
            dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
        });
    });
```

Comment: JS part worked for me, just without ``theme: "bootstrap4"`` line

Comment: Yeah, just adding `dropdownParent: $(this).parent()` to the JS initialization solved it